# How to align the first container based on second container?

Tags: html, css, styles, alignment

Below is my code in html and CSS. Current [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrsQb.png) and my desired [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24v14.jpg) with red.

```css
.product-detail-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* width: 97%; */
  max-width: 1200px;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2.5rem 5%;
}

.product-detail-container .path {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-family: var(--fontCommon);
  display: flex;
  color: black;
}
.product-detail-container .path a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}
.product-detail-container .photo {
  width: 45%;
}

.product-detail-container .photo img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.description {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-detail-container">
  <div class="path">
    <a class="path" href="/index.html">All products/</a>
    <p class="path" id="path-product-title">product-title</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex; margin-top: 30px; justify-content: center">
    <div class="photo" id="product-photo">
      <img src="/assets/products/1.jpg" class="photo" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <p class="product-title" id="product-title">product-title</p>
      <p class="product-id" id="product-id">product-id</p>
      <p
        class="product-price"
        id="product-price"
        style="margin-top: 2vh">
        product-price
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the path which is "All products/chocolate" align with the photo below it but I need to keep the all element inside .product-detail-container CENTER. How to achieve?

Comment: A few styles are probably missing in the code you pasted. When running it, it does not look like the image you posted. Can you update it to make it look like the image?

Answer (score 1):

Removing `justify-content: center` from the inline style fixes the `path` and `product-detail` alignment. Once you have that, you can work on aligning `<div class="product-detail-container">` where you want. See the snippet bellow. I also added borders in the elements to make it easier to see.

```css
.product-detail-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* width: 97%; */
  max-width: 1200px;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2.5rem 5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.product-detail-container .path {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-family: var(--fontCommon);
  display: flex;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

/* to fix vertical alignment */
.product-detail-container .path-item {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.product-detail-container .path-item a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}

/* moved inline style to this class */
.product-detail {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* justify-content: center */
}

.product-detail-container .photo {
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  width: 45%;
}

.product-detail-container .photo img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.description {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1; /* added this */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-detail-container">
  <div class="path">
    <a class="path-item" href="/index.html">All products/</a>
    <p class="path-item" id="path-product-title">product-title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="product-detail">
    <div class="photo" id="product-photo">
      <img src="/assets/products/1.jpg" class="photo" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <p class="product-title" id="product-title">product-title</p>
      <p class="product-id" id="product-id">product-id</p>
      <p
        class="product-price"
        id="product-price"
        style="margin-top: 2vh">
        product-price
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```